# Javascript: Preserving event hooks and state by updating DOM with only changed nodes or minimum number of potentially changed nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So for example if we have a flash video already buffered and playing, or an autocomplete active with input, focus, and a dropdown visible (and maybe even loading something) but only have HTML of the full document and a copy of the HTML earlier, how can we merge them into the live DOM without the user's state being interrupted?

Ordinarily I'd just program a specific fix, specifying the right area to change given it's div name, manually but that is not a known variable for the situation at hand (I'm programming a Pythonic MVC framework with AJAX).

I want to change the smallest amount of nodes, and probably the deepest nodes that I can get away with.

It's ok to require ID's for some of the nodes (e.g: flash or autocomplete widget) but not possible to expect this for all nodes - so in some situations perhaps node position and types will be available to compare documents.

I understand this will not be a complete solution but in some cases it will be all that is required.

Comment: You're trying to partially update the DOM as you would in a usual AJAX call, but you can't modify the server response which only sends a full page response, so you're trying to minimize updates to the DOM to only changed nodes. Am I anywhere close to the actual problem? Also, if the above is correct, what is your motivation in changing minimal number of nodes - performance, preserving state as much as possible, etc..? This ideally shouldn't be community wiki as there could be multiple answers but it is not a subjective question by any means.

Comment: It may be possible to change the server response but I'd like controller logic to be on the client side where possible because it could make further operations easier where events really do need to be reassigned or such. It would also be a more general solution for a JS based app. I think an initial starting DOM could be diffed server side if bandwidth became an issue but I'd still like to do the merging on the client side. Thanks for your thoughts on it (and the wiki note).